# Why popover not close when click outside in popper.js?

Tags: element-ui, popper.js

I use element ui's `el-popover` to show my popover. But when I click outside of the popover, the popover won't be closed. Maybe I blocked some events to body or some other elements used by `popper.js`. Please gime me some advices or is it possible to specify an element for `popper.js` to handle events for closing the popover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some element blocked click mouse event when propagation.